# How to write awk script to show all the lines/records between the specified range entered by user?

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

Suppose this the `data.lst`

```
Anil Sharma, Vaishali Nagar, science, 45, 67
Manoj Gupta, Sri Nagar Road, commerce, 66, 89
Kamal Sharma, Shastri Nagar, commerce, 81, 32
Rama Sharma, Vaishali Nagar, commerce, 45, 91
Chirag Harwani, Vaishali Nagar, science, 34, 63
```

and I want to write an `awk` script to show all the lines/records between the
specified range, to be entered by the user.

This is what I have written so far,

```
desiredact.awk
BEGIN{
 printf "Enter the initial range: "
 getline n1 < "/dev/tty"
 printf "Enter the last range: "
 getline n2 < "/dev/tty"
 }
```

How to proceed further? Yes, ranges are the Line numbers.

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  What have you tried?  How did it not work as expected or intended?

Comment: Range of what? Line numbers? If so, this can be done with sed: `sed -n 3,5p data.lst` prints lines 3, 4 and 5. Also, I second @DopeGhoti's request: Show us the program you have written so far.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I've edited the questions kindly look. I don't know how to take line numbers (range) from users and then create a condition for the range.

Comment: @berndbausch Yes, line numbers. I've edited the question and have written the script.

Comment: Personally, I don't think you should use awk for user interaction if it can be avoided; in your case, I would acquire the ranges using a shell script and then call awk or sed with these ranges. To expand on your code: Check whether the current line is inside the range and print it when that's the case, e.g. `NR>=n1 && NR<=n2 { print }`. However, the `sed` code I suggested is better in my opinion, since more compact.

Comment: @berndbausch thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to provide the start and end of the range desired to be output *to* `awk` as variables rather than try to parse them in-flight in the `BEGIN` block:

```
$ awk -v rangestart=3 -v rangeend=5 'NR >= rangestart && NR <= rangeend { print }' inputfile
Kamal Sharma, Shastri Nagar, commerce, 81, 32
Rama Sharma, Vaishali Nagar, commerce, 45, 91
Chirag Harwani, Vaishali Nagar, science, 34, 63
```